# Date.now() cannot be updated in Float32Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, date

In Float32Array a date can only be set once as a value. Further updates make no difference. Run the snippet below and see(Chrome, Firefox, IE).

Is there a workaround? I must have current time as one of the values of Float32Array.

```js
var d1 = document.querySelector('#d1');
var d2 = document.querySelector('#d2');
var d3 = document.querySelector('#d3');

var fa = new Float32Array(1);
var date;
setInterval(function() {
  date = Date.now();
  fa[0] = 52343225; // another value to clear the previous value - doesn't help
  fa[0] = date;

  d1.textContent = date;
  d2.textContent = fa[0];
  d3.textContent = date - fa[0];

}, 50);
```

```html
<div>Date: <span id="d1"></span>
</div>
<div>Float32Array value: <span id="d2"></span>
</div>
<div>Difference: <span id="d3"></span>
</div>

<p>As you can see above the date in Float32Array is not changing. Initially the date is set in the FUTURE</p>
```

```
new Date().getTime() // gives the same result
performance.now() // works correctly
```

What is interesting is that the date is always set one minute in the future from opening a tab. Even page refresh is not resetting this timer. Only opening a new tab and running the script starts the countdown.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the a 32bit float can't properly handle the date value.  I switched to a float64 which is working just fine.

```js
var d1 = document.querySelector('#d1');
var d2 = document.querySelector('#d2');
var d3 = document.querySelector('#d3');

// CHANGED HERE
var fa = new Float64Array(1);
var date;
setInterval(function() {
  date = Date.now();
  fa[0] = 52343225; // another value to clear the previous value - doesn't help
  fa[0] = date;

  d1.textContent = date;
  d2.textContent = fa[0];
  d3.textContent = date - fa[0];

}, 50);
```

```html
<div>Date: <span id="d1"></span>
</div>
<div>Float32Array value: <span id="d2"></span>
</div>
<div>Difference: <span id="d3"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Will it have a big impact on memory? I'm using tens of these arrays with hundreds of fields in my project.

Comment: Not to be snarky, but -- does it really matter? That's the datatype that works.   Depending on exactly what you are measuring, you might be able to truncate off the high bits (and no, you cant use standard bit-wise operators, because those values exceed Int32's)  and save some space, but otherwise-- that's it.  That said, if you're running on a desktop, I wouldn't even blink about using 10,000 of these or so.  Look at the filesize of some of the bigger graphics and see how much RAM they take.